# Best way to send 3rd party credentials via REST API

Tags: java, rest

I have exposed a REST API to be consumed by the set of internal applications. When an application calls the API it executes a 3rd party application for certain operations. To execute this it is required to send an userid and a password. REST API does not keep the credentils and the internal applications should send them in the POST request. What is the best way to send them. In the body with other data or header. I planned to use something like this `Authorization: Basic Base64(UserName:Password).` 
Please advice?

Comment: This is a bit unclear, but it _sounds_ like you should be using OAuth2.

Comment: The 3rd party application which is triggered by the REST API requires userid/password in every request. And those will be sent by the internal applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you describe sending the username and the password in the header (encoding the username and password into a base64 format) will work until you retrieve an auth token. Once you get an auth token you should send that in the header instead of your username and password.

Comment: Thank you @Jaesheon. The 3rd party application does not send any token. The internal applications will have to send the userid/password in every request.

Comment: @Kevin I guess it's not ideal but sending the username and password should be okay. You should change your route from GET to POST if possible (if you were using GET).

Comment: @Jaeheson. Thank you